# ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected while updating Websphere application

Tags: bash, websphere, war

I am trying to execute a command as user Webas to update the application with new WAR file. I am getting ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected. The command I am trying to execute is :

su - webas -c AdminApp.update('productx', 'app', ['-operation', 'update', '-contents', '/apps/deploy/productX.war', '-usedefaultbindings', '-nodeployejb'])

How do I execute this statement without errors? and will this command update the Websphere application with the new WAR file?

Comment: `AdminApp.update(...)` does not look like a shell (ksh here) command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the entire wsadmin command (so from `AdminApp` to the end) in double quotes (`"`) to prevent `ksh` from trying to interperet the wsadmin command as a ksh statement.

```
su - webas -c "AdminApp.update('productx', 'app', ['-operation', 'update', '-contents', '/apps/deploy/productX.war', '-usedefaultbindings', '-nodeployejb'])"
```

Comment: still getting the same error even after enclosing in quotes.

Comment: Try inverting the quotes, so single quotes enclose the whole command and double quotes are used within the wsadmin command where single quotes are now. Double quotes usually still have some shell processing, but I believe single quotes will tell ksh to take the whole string verbatim and not attempt to interpret it.

`su - webas -c 'AdminApp.update("productx", "app", ["-operation", "update", "-contents", "/apps/deploy/productX.war", "-usedefaultbindings", "-nodeployejb"])'`

Comment: Another alternative might be to place the wsadmin command without quotes (so starting at `AdminApp` and going to the end of that command into a file and then specify the file instead, so `su - webas -f update.py`. I'm assuming `webas` passes its parameters to wsadmin.sh so the `-f` parameter will be valid.